# How can I achieve a full-sized image in open graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am using the facebook plugin on my wordpress website. My posts are image-only. I am able get the open graph functionality to work, however the image is either a tiny thumbnail with a useless excerpt box beside it, or full-sized with half of it cut of because of the useless caption box.

Now, I say useless, but I wouldn't mind having only my url presented below the image if possible, but without all the extra space. It looks terrible. Also, My image posts do not have titles so in the excerpts box the only title option without a separator for the "collection" theme I am using is sitenameonly....which leave my

sitename

site url

< .........huge extra excerpt space..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................>

I have looked elsewhere, in fact all over but can't find information to:

1. make images full-sized (as if they were posted directly to facebook)
2. Remove extra space in the excerpt box, leaving only the url
   (or remove the box entirely--leaving a full-sized image)

thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

As long as your Wordpress plugin assigns a proper image to each post using the `og:image` tag and the conditions stated below (emphasis added) then you should be able to get full size posts.

> We've increased the size of images in link page posts by 4x on mobile
>   and 8x on desktop to help you drive better fan engagement. As part of
>   this change, we've also made the aspect ratios for images consistent
>   across mobile and desktop. We recommend the following steps to
>   optimize your images for this new format:
>
> 1. Use images that are **1200 x 630px** or greater for the best display on high-resolution devices. At the minimum you should use images that are
>      600 x 315px to display link page posts with larger images.
> 2. Use images that have an aspect ratio of **1.91:1**. Try to keep your images as close to this aspect ratio as possible to avoid any cropping
>      in News Feed.
> 3. Use the **`og:image`** tag to choose the image that you want to share. If you don't use the og:image tag, users can choose the image they want
>      to post, giving them a chance to select an image that is poor quality.

Source: [Larger Images for Link Page Posts](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/09/18/platform-updates--facebook-ios-sdk-3-8--larger-images-for-link-page-posts--and-custom-audiences-upda/)